# Mathematical induction proof for $A_n = [-1 + \frac{1}{2n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$, $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ = $]-1, 1[$

Tags: induction

$ \forall \in \mathbb{N} $, let $A_n = [-1 + \frac{1}{2n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$, find $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$.

I know (hypothesize) that the answer is tending towards $$]-1,1[$$
and that $$A_n \cup A_{n+1} = A_{n+1}$$ hence $$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n \cup A_{n+1} = A_{n+1} = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_{n+1}$$
How can I prove that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n =$ $]-1, 1[$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n =]-1, 1[$, it is enough to prove both inclusions.

$\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\subseteq]-1, 1[$ is true since for each $n$, $A_n\subseteq ]-1,1[$.

For the reverse inclusion, let $-1<x<1$ be arbitrary. If there are $N$ and $M$ such that $x\ge -1+\frac1{2N}$ and $x\le 1-\frac1M$, then $x\in A_{N+M}$, so we are done. I will leave why such $N,M$ exist to you.